# unity switch cameras by UI Buttons

Tags: camera, unityscript

Have a problem with my sript. I need to switch an array of cameras by 2 buttons. But I have a problem with my counter. It doesn't work right, when i try to change cameras back and forward.

```
public void Pressed () { 

    if (Next == true) {
        currCamIndex ++;
        Debug.Log ("index = " + currCamIndex);
        if (currCamIndex < cameras.Length) {
            cameras [currCamIndex - 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
            cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        } else {
            cameras [currCamIndex - 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
            currCamIndex = 0;
            cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        }
    }
    if (Prev == true) {
        currCamIndex --;
        if (currCamIndex >= 0) {
            cameras [currCamIndex + 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
            cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        } else {
            cameras [currCamIndex + 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
            currCamIndex = cameras.Length-1;
            cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        }
    }

    if (Back == true) {
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tag of the active camera to "MainCamera" and the inactive camera to "Untagged" or something else:

```
public void Pressed () { 

if (Next == true) {
    currCamIndex ++;
    Debug.Log ("index = " + currCamIndex);
    if (currCamIndex < cameras.Length) {
        cameras [currCamIndex - 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        cameras [currCamIndex - 1].gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.tag = "MainCamera";
    } else {
        cameras [currCamIndex - 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
        cameras [currCamIndex - 1].gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
        currCamIndex = 0;
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.tag = "MainCamera";
    }
}
if (Prev == true) {
    currCamIndex --;
    if (currCamIndex >= 0) {
        cameras [currCamIndex + 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        cameras [currCamIndex + 1].gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.tag = "MainCamera";
    } else {
        cameras [currCamIndex + 1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
        cameras [currCamIndex + 1].gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
        currCamIndex = cameras.Length-1;
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        cameras [currCamIndex].gameObject.tag = "MainCamera";
    }
}

if (Back == true) {
    Application.LoadLevel(0);
}
```

The code is a bit repetitive with the multiple branchings of SetActive calls and the tag reassignments.  If it was my code I would eliminate such redundancy, but this code example is fine for illustration purposes.

Comment: Oh..i forgot about this question. I decided this problem with statis variables  currCamindex.